# Asynchronous request queue size limitation

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I am using Cassandra Java Driver 2.0 in asynchronous mode. When I am executing a lot of operations very intensively they must be queued somewhere inside driver before they sent to network.

I would like to set the queue size limit. I haven't found any Java Driver parameters for that. Also I expect something similar to RejectedExecutionHandler mechanism in ThreadPoolExecotor. Is it possible to do somehow with Cassandra Java Driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't set the **queue size** limit. What you need is possibly the [PoolingOptions](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/PoolingOptions.html). The queuing depends on the nodes capability of accepting more requests. If what you're trying is to tune the capability before queueing probably PoolingOptions is the answer, if what you want is to tune the max-size of the queue to reject further requests, afaik, you can't. However you can always pull an improvement-request [here](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel)

Comment: To handle rejected queries, you can always catch `NoHostAvailableException` and do your handling there.

Comment: Carlo,
It seems like you are right. After digging into the code I also haven't found such a possibility. I posted this one JIRA issue for Cassandra Java Driver: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-412

Olivier, NoHostAvailableException if fine. Just I need also to control/monitor the queue which is not the same.

Comment: For future visitors, PoolingOptions has now a setter for the queue size.